# C++ array/matrix in a file

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

completely new to C++ and I have to use this programming language. And never done programming before.

Basically I need to read a matrix from a stored file so it's output can be seen when you press the debug button.

When I've tried doing the matrix

```
1 3 5

2 4 6

5 7 9
```

When I come to reading it, it comes up with the matrix but in a line so.... 1 3 5 2 4 6 5 7 9.

So does anybody know how to get it so it's read as a matrix, if that's possible?

In the future I then need to find the determinant of the matrix e.t.c. And do other sums between multiple matrices.

Here is what I currently have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    char filename[50];
    ifstream matrixA;
    cin.getline(filename, 50);
    matrixA.open(filename);

    if (!matrixA. is_open())
    {
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    char word[50];
    matrixA >> word;
    while (matrixA.good())
    {
        cout << word << " ";
        matrixA >> word;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a look to this example http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/41244/

Comment: You are expected to show some efforts what you already have tried.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of 9 numbers, you can read them in with an `ifstream` object

```
float elements[9];

ifstream reader(/*your file*/);

reader >> elements[0] >> elements[1] >> elements[2]; //read first line
reader >> elements[3] >> elements[4] >> elements[5]; //read second line
reader >> elements[6] >> elements[7] >> elements[8]; //read third line

reader.close();
```

Better still you can create a class / structure for your matrix and read it in using a member function, and add operators (such as the determinant).

EDIT:

If you just want to print the matrix in... matrix form, just use `std::getline`;

```
ifstream reader(/*your file*/);

char buffer[300];

//1st line
std::getline(reader, buffer);
cout << buffer << endl;

//2nd line
std::getline(reader, buffer);
cout << buffer << endl;

//3nd line
std::getline(reader, buffer);
cout << buffer << endl;

reader.close();
```

This does however assume you are actually format the data as a matrix.

Comment: Hmm I just tried this but it didn't work.. It's probably right I just don't know what I'm doing.. hmm :(

Comment: @user3536870 Why didn't it work? Did you get a runtime/compiler error, or were the numbers read incorrectly?

Comment: The black box opened but closed straight away and it was blank for the half a second it was open

Comment: @user3536870 from your code it looks as if the program closed with the `EXIT_FAILURE` flag. Check that the file your are opening exists and is in the right directory.

Comment: @user3536870 BTW the 'black box' is called a _console_ :)

Comment: It finds the file that I want using the code I've given but it just gives it in a straight line rather than a 3x3 matrix. And however you do the store thing in c++ I need to go on and perform functions on it

Comment: @user3536870 Ah you mean you want to actually _print_ this in matrix form? Just use `std::getline` to read each line into a buffer and `cout`-it.

Comment: Yep I want the program to read a file (with my matrix in) and print the elements onto the screen.

Comment: It still won't work for some reason it tells me that getline is undefined, thanks a lot for trying to help though. Just a bit useless at this unfortunately

Comment: @user3536870 Sorry about that man... dunno why you're getting that error - std::getline should come with `<fstream>`.

Comment: It's doing my head in.. really appreciate the help though mate, cheers!

Comment: @user3536870 Don't mention it... tell me about it man, C++ sucks (but also rules in some respects... somehow).